# How to parse the "middle" field(s) in either AWK or PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, awk

I have data that looks like this:

```
1 company 123
2 company name 321
3 company name, Inc. 456
```

Each line contains three fields. The position, the company's name, and the last set of numbers it their index.

I know in AWK I could do something like this:

```
% cat companylist.txt | awk ' { print $1} '
```

Which would handle the position number fine. And using $NF would get the last number which is the index. But what about the middle field for the company name? How do I parse that so that I end up with three fields for position,company name, index.

This can be done in AWK or PHP for my needs, thanks!

Comment: You're not using delimiters which will make this mission near impossible if the company names contains a space

Comment: That's the format the data was provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that checks for a string between two numbers that are anchored at the start and the end.

Something like:

```
#^\d+\s+(.*)\s+\d+$#
 ^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^ anchor numbers to end and start with at least one space after and before
```

Using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on a string:

```
$pattern = '#^\d+\s+(.*)\s+\d+$#';
preg_match($pattern, $one_line_of_list, $matches);
```

**Edit:** To capture the numbers as well, just change the pattern to:

```
$pattern = '#^(\d+)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)$#';
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a working code example of this in PHP? Thanks!

Comment: @Edward I have added an example, check the manual for more details.

Comment: That worked out, thanks! Last question, how would I parse to get the first field (the position number) and the last (the index number)? I'm new to regular expressions.

Comment: @Edward The parenthesis capture output, so you can capture all groups with `#^(\d+)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)$#`

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a source for the data, i.e. text doc ect. I couldn't include the lines of code to read the data from the source, so you would need to add something to the beginning to loop through where the data comes from. Once you get it in, and create the looping mechanism, you can use this bit of code to get your data formated into 3 variables then do something else with it.

```
<?php
$string=line; // get a single line into the $string variable, from a loop or whatever.
$linearray=explode(' ', $string);
$lastplace=count($linearray)-1; // subtract 1 to account for starting from 0 in array
$position=$linearray[0]; // first one will always be the position
$index=$linearray[$lastplace]; // last one will always be the index
$i=1; //starting array position for your while loop
$companyname=""; //start company name with an empty string
while($i<$lastplace){ //cycle through all the middle chunks of the array to get the     company name
    $companyname.=$linearray[$i]; //adds any bits in the middle to the company name
    $companyname.=" "//adds a space in case there are more parts to add to it
    $i++;
}
// add function here to do something with the data

?>
```

You can even make it fancier and create some sort of check to not add the last space if it is the last part of the company name

Answer (score 1):

This is not a regular input file, is it not TAB-separated, for example. If it is like that, that there is a first field and a last field and any number of fields in the middle that should be regarded as one field, one could do something like this:

```
awk '{$1=$NF=""; $0=$0; $1=$1}1' file
```

if the number of spaces between the words in the middle "field" is not important.
Otherwise you could try:

```
awk '{gsub("^" $1 "[ \t]*|[ \t]*" $NF "$","")}1' file
```